# Export Viso 2013 Models as xml file so that it can be imported in Sparx EA

Tags: visio

I am building models in Visio 2013 and would like to export them as xml file for importing into Sparx EA tool. How do I do this.
Ramani

Comment: It looks like Sparx EA can import from Visio directly? Why XML?
http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/visio-importer/moving-from-visio-to-enterprise-architect.html

Comment: My visio diagram has lot of AWS Icons and Sparx does not import correctly

Comment: I think you could ask sparx to fix it for you then..? They specifically built their addin to import visio, so if there was a way through xml, they could have used it.